# How to make a license to prohibit redistribution?

Tags: licensing

I have a script I want to sell. It's written in PHP, but that's not relevant here I guess. I want to secure my script with a license, so the buyer is forbidden from redistributing it.

This is the first time I am selling my own script, so I have no idea how to start with this. Please let me know how I can protect my script with a license and what kind of license.

Comment: IANAL, but in most Western countries, unless you explicitly provide a license which allows redistribution, redistribution of other peoples' copyrighted works is prohibited by law. No need for any sort of license for that.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 7):

1. Don't ask mostly anonymous people on the Internet for legal advice.
2. Look around at the commercial software you already have and read their licenses.
3. Look at your competition's licenses (they're often available on the web site, no purchase required.
4. If you find one you like, consider having your own lawyer (familiar with the laws in your country) take a look at it.

Comment: +1 especially for 1 and 4.

Comment: 5. If you are selling your software -- charge enough to pay the Lawyer from #4 to answer these questions.